# Default permissions for new users in OS X Server

Tags: macos, osx-server, permission, user-account

I'm creating mobile users in MT Lion Server through Workgroup Manager 10.8. I've set it up so that when the user logs in to the client machine, the network share point auto mounts. This gives access to their home folder on the network.

The issue is that they now have read/write permissions for every other user folder in that share point. Instead of having to go through every user's folder to modify the permissions, is there an automatic way to have the right permissions when the user is created in the first place?

I basically need 'staff'=none, 'other'=none, and for some reason there's a 'Everyone'=custom which doesn't even need to be there. Is it possible to get those configurations at user creation?

Comment: I am no longer using Workgroup Manager, but have switched over to Server.app and Profile Manager. However, if I create an OD user in Server.app, assign it a Network Home through the GUI interface there, and set the home folder to mount automatically at login, we have no issues of that user being able to see other user's folders. Have you set the user's to mount their network home or to mount the share point that contains the network homes? Have you setup an ACE on the share point that may have inadvertently given extra permissions to your users?

Comment: What is the path to each home folder and what settings / ACL have you set in Server app? I usually make a new share called /Shared Items/UserHome and tick the **Make available for home directories over AFP** item to tell server to handle user ACL properly. I'll try to test this with Workgroup Manager in the coming days to see if anything else is needed.